# My macbook freezes after logging in except in safe mode

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, performance

Whenever I start my mac it freezes few seconds after logging in except if I keep on moving my trackpad but when I stop it freezes after few seconds.

OS Version: mac os x 10.9.5
I have tried:

- Resetting SMC
- Resetting PRAM
- DiskRepair in Recovery mode which shows no errors
- Reinstalling OSX
- Checking and removing Login items

But I still behaves the same.
I also tried switching to Linux and it worked perfectly well.

Name of file at /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
`com.apple.Webkit.WebContent_2022-01-06-131843_Elemsimons-MacBook-Pro.crash`
Please do anybody have any idea.

Comment: What kind of Mac, what kind of mouse? Is it connected directly or via a hub? What happens if you use another mouse?

Comment: Macbook pro 2014. About the mouse, I meant trackpad.

Comment: How old is the battery?

Comment: Like 7 years now. I even tried changing the os to linux and it worked. The battery life was decent.

Comment: It could be swollen nevertheless. But the fact that the problem doesn‘t occur on Linux may be worth adding to the question.

Comment: 1. What version (10.xx.yy) of macOS are you running? 2. Can you amend your question with a code block containing the names of files found in `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`? I want to see if any crash or panic reports were generated.

Comment: Yes a crash report was generated. It indicates: Responsible: Safari [265]. The macbook pro version is mac os x 10.9.5

Comment: Please re-read my comment: Can you **amend your question** with a **code block** containing the **names of files** found in `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`?

Comment: I have added it

Comment: @ElemSimon You had only **one** file in that directory? I find that difficult to believe. Do you ever see a `Your computer has restarted because of a problem` message after you reboot?